# How to show that $Z/12Z×Z/90Z×Z/25Z$ and $Z/100Z×Z/30Z×Z/9Z$ are isomorph?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

How to show that $G = \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/90 \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/25 \Bbb Z$ and  $H = \Bbb Z/100 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z$ are isomorph?

The way I would go is to use the decomposition in primary groups:

For G:

- $12 = 2^2 * 3$
- $90 = 3^2*2*5$
- $25 = 5^2$

So $G \simeq G(2) \times G(3) \times G(5)$ with

- $G(2)= (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/2^2\Bbb Z)$
- $G(3)= (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/3^2\Bbb Z)$
- $G(5)= (\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/5^2\Bbb Z)$

For H:

- $100 = 5^2 * 2^2$
- $30 = 5*3*2$
- $9 = 3^2$

So $H \simeq H(2) \times H(3) \times H(5)$ with

- $H(2)= (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/2^2\Bbb Z)$
- $H(3)= (\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/3^2\Bbb Z)$
- $H(5)= (\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/5^2\Bbb Z)$

As $G$ and $H$ have the same decomposition they are isomorph.

Is it right?
Is there a better/faster/easier way to prove it?

Comment: That’s pretty much the way I’d have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have displayed it this way.

\begin{align}
   \mathbb Z_{12} × \mathbb Z_{90} × \mathbb Z_{25}
   &\cong (\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_3) \times
         (\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_9 \times \mathbb Z_5) \times
         (\mathbb Z_{25}) \\
   &\cong (\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_{25}) \times
         (\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_5) \times
         (\mathbb Z_9) \\
   &\cong \mathbb Z_{100} × \mathbb Z_{30} × \mathbb Z_9
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Your proof using the primary decomposition is fine and systematic.

You can also use the Chinese remainder theorem to recombine the factors into the invariant factor decomposition:

$
G
= \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/90 \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/25 \Bbb Z
\cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/9 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/10 \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/25 \Bbb Z
\cong \Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/900 \Bbb Z
$

$
H 
= \Bbb Z/100 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z
\cong \Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/100 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/9\Bbb Z
\cong \Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/900 \Bbb Z
$

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I have trouble understanding the invariant factor decomposition, Wikipedia is not very explicit, any resource to understand it better? Like how to choose which $Z/nZ$ you recombine together or not ?

Comment: @astudentofmaths, $H$ was easy and then I made $G$ follow $H$.